# How correctly add my tests' errors to a stack so the tests don't stop executing?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I use SeleniumWebdriver C# to build automated tests. 
I also use NUnit to mark test methods (so I can run them).

In each of the tests there are several verification and when the first verification fails then the test stops executing (an exception is thrown).

I want the test to continue executing so more errors could be found!

Please guys, give me a clue how to do it right.

I think about something like that:

1. Instead of throwing Exception in verification I'll add an error to a stack
2. When a test ends I check if my stack is not empty
3. If the stack is not empty I push to console all errors and fail the test
4. If the stack is empty then the test passed successfully.

Are these steps good? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved my problem in the next way**:

1. I've created a set of methods that are performed once prior to executing any of the tests ([TestFixtureSetUpAttribute] in NUnit);
2. In this set of methods I do the main actions results of which I'll check (in my case I buy a lottery ticket);
3. In each test ([Test] in NUnit) I check one assertion.

So now I have a main action that doesn't include any verification. After this actions is completed I check all needed assertions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you.

```
class Asserts
{
    private static StringBuilder _stack;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _stack = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (_stack.Lenght != 0) Assert.Fail(_stack.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        AssertHelper(() => Assert.AreEqual(0, 0));
        AssertHelper(() => Assert.IsNotNull(null));
        AssertHelper(() => Assert.AreEqual(3, 4));
        AssertHelper(() => Assert.AreEqual(1, 1));          
    }

    private static void AssertHelper(Action assert)
    {
        try
        {
            assert();
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            _stack.Append(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But the good idea is to keep one verification per one test.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want your tests to only be verifying one thing at a time. If there's 2 steps to an action that require asserting, considering having tests like:

```
UserForm_FirstNameMissing_ThrowsException
UserForm_SecondNameMissing_ThrowsException
UserForm_AgeTooLarge_ThrowsException
```

instead of having a single test called something like:

```
UserForm_TestValidation
```

This means that - like you wanted - if one stage of validation fails, you can continue to test the rest. Your best bet for this may be a singular test with a dataset, however keeping the answer simple yet relevant, a test per failure state is good enough for what you want.

Comment: What if I have to check buying a product and I have to check: price on the front page, discount, price at the back-end etc. If I run different tests to check all these details it's gonna take enormous amount of time, isn't it?

Comment: It may very well do, but the tests themselves should be as concise as possible to try and cut down repetition. Do you have a regular unit test suite as well as your Selenium tests, for testing your back end in isolation? Or is it all being done through the front end?

Comment: There are no unit tests, only tests written using Selenium. I test front-end and back-end using them. By back-end I mean admin panel of the site.

Comment: If that's the case you may have to live with the amount of time it will take. It's outside the scope of the question, but you should consider adding unit tests for your individual classes to reduce the amount of error checking required in your Selenium tests, thus reducing your test runtime.